# Proof involving order axioms for real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

If $x$ has the property that $$\space0\leq x < h$$$$\forall\space h\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$$ then $$x=0$$ 
My "educated" guess is that if you have a $x>0$ then the statement does not hold for all $h\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$. But I don't know how to fit it together formally. Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $x>0$, there exists a real number  $h$ ($=\frac{x}{2}$ for example) such that
$$0 < h < x. $$

Comment: Ah, but what axiom or reasoning from axioms tells you that $\frac{x}{2} < x$ for $x>0$?

Comment: $0<1$ implies $0<1<2$ (adding 1 and both sides) and $0 < x < 2x$, since $x>0$. Then, since $\frac12 >0$, we conclude that $0 < \frac{x}{2} < x$.

Comment: Is it the axiom that says that if $x$ and $y$ $\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$ then $x+y$ and $xy$ will also be in $\mathbb{R^{+}}$. We know that $0.5\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$ so if $x>0$ then $x\cdot0.5\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$

Answer (score 0):

1. $2^{-1}+2^{-1}=1$. Indeed, $2(2^{-1}+2^{-1})=2\cdot2^{-1}+2\cdot2^{-1}=1+1=2$; from $2(2^{-1}+2^{-1})=2$ we get the thesis (multiply both sides by $2^{-1}$).
2. $2^{-1}>0$. Otherwise $2^{-1}<0$, so $1=2^{-1}+2^{-1}<0$, a contradiction.
3. $2^{-1}<1$. Otherwise $2^{-1}\ge1$, so $1=2^{-1}+2^{-1}\ge1+1=2$, a contradiction.

Therefore $0<2^{-1}<1$ and, if $x>0$,
$$
0<2^{-1}x<x
$$

Answer (score 0):

As was said above, you prove this by asuming $x > 0$ and finding a number $h$ such that $0 < h < x$. I can think of a couple of different approaches to find this $h$, I hope you find them useful.

I. Since $0 < \frac{1}{2}$, adding $\frac{1}{2}$ to both sides gives you $\frac{1}{2} < 1$ (because $x \leq y \Rightarrow x + z \leq y + z$). Then, $x > 0$ and $0 < \frac{1}{2} < 1$ imply $0 < \frac{x}{2} < x$ (because if $x > 0$ and $y < z$ then $xy < xz$). Thus finding $h = \frac{x}{2}$.

II. While not an order axiom, you can use the *archimedean property* of $\mathbb{R}$: For every $x > 0$ there's an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0 < \frac{1}{n} < x$. Here, $h$ would be the $\frac{1}{n}$ guaranteed by said property.